# What changes does Unity's HUD offer

Tags: 12.04, hud

In 12.04 there will be many changes to the application menus. For what I have heard HUD will make some of this changes but what does it actually offer for newcomers and old users of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though, HUD is still under development, one of the biggest +'s, in my opinion, is searching the capabilities within the program, rather than searching through menus and submenus. Again, this update might seem like an inconvenient feature, although that's biassed opinion without giving time to get used to.

Answer (score 1):

I do not wish to offer an opinion as this site is the place for answers to questions and not for expressing opinions.

I have installed HUD. And I have been trying to work out what it does and how to test it. I have found this link:

[Ubuntu wiki link on HUD](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PaulSladen/HUD)

Based on my experience of the last few hours this is my answer.

How will it affect new users? Not much. They will not even know it is there. There will need to be a lot of documentation to explain what this innovation can do for the user.

How will it affect old (experienced) users of Ubuntu? Not much unless they change the way they work. In using Unity I have been trained to use the mouse to access the Launcher, the Dash and the global menu. To benefit from HUD I now need to train myself to use the keyboard more than at present.

I understand that HUD will get used to the way we work. When we use HUD to find an application or a file HUD will present us with options based on our previous work pattern. This will benefit all those who make use of HUD.

The effects of this feature will only become apparent as HUD is developed. It needs applications that cooperate with it. It is a very clever at what it does but at the moment I am wondering what is the point of it. At present it does not do anything that I am not already in the habit of doing another way.

The publicity about HUD is great but I need instruction in how to get the best out of it.  Otherwise I may just continue in the same way of working. Perhaps more features will be available as HUD is updated over the coming weeks.

Regards.

Comment: So it is giving the user a keyboard way of accessing faster menus that would normally be access with the mouse? I am actually a user that enjoys using the keyboard more when time is of the essence. For example accessing the terminal with the mouse takes longer that attaching a key for the terminal or typing "te" in the dash.